# Center and fix padding for Responsive, Anamorphic youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

Here is the code for the video that I have and the website that it is on:

```
<center><style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 37.5%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 78.105%; height: 78.105%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/R-5G2NvjfQk' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='1'></iframe></div></center>
```

www.speakingclips.blogspot.com

For some reason I'm not able to center and get rid of the spacing below the responsive, anamorphic youtube video. I need the responsive-ness and ratio to stay the same, but centered and less padding on the bottom.

Thank you!

Comment: can i see your demo by snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated the questions so it shows the code. Is this what you meant by the snippet?

Comment: A snippet on StackOverflow is a runnable example. See the button that looks like a piece of paper with the < > symbols

Answer (score 1):

Since the container is set to maintain it's aspect ratio using no height and the padding set with a percentage, you can absolutely position the video in the center. Set the video to 50% from the left and top of the container and then adjust it back up and left by 50% of its height and width. It's clean, cross-browser, and your 78.105% value can be changed and the element will remain centered.

```css
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 37.5%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 78.105%;
  height: 78.105%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX( -50%) translateY( -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='embed-container'>
  <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/R-5G2NvjfQk' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='1'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Also, there's some spacing on the top and bottom of the video. I changed the percentage from 78.105% to 100% on my site to have the spaces be covered with video, but the video is a bit too big because it does the full with of the site. Is there a way to have the max video width be 1063px with the same responsive properties?

Comment: Yeah, try setting that max width on the embed container instead of 100% and I think it will behave the way you want

Comment: That did work thank you! But now when I extend my browser size & gets past 1063px in width, the height of the video starts to add black bars. Is there a way for the height of the video to keep the same Anamorphic ratio when the website size increases?

Comment: Add a link? I'm not picturing it.

Comment: If you drag the corner of your browser to make the site bigger or smaller, you'll see that when it gets too big there will be black bars on the top & bottom of the video

Comment: Set `max-width: 1063px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` on the `center` element and your bars are gone.

Comment: You are saying to add this?

`.center {
max-width: 1063px;
margin: 0 auto;
}`

If so then it didn't seem to work for me. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Your center element on the page is a tag, not a class, so you target it with `center` not `.center` - no dot at the start